# continuous extension from closed ball to whole plane

Tags: real-analysis

$g:B\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function, I want to know how to extend this function  on whole plane? B is closed unit disk. I know the fact for closed interval, how to extend in whole real line. please give hint.

Comment: Check the Tietze extension theorem for more abstract spaces(it works here as well).

Comment: ... if you like killing flies with a sledgehammer.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes sure. At first, I didnt notice that $B$ is a subset of $R^2$.

Comment: Another hint: For any $\vec x\in\mathbb R^2\setminus B$, consider $\vec x/\lVert\vec x\rVert\in B$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: make it constant on rays from the origin outside the disk.

Comment: $f$ be the extension,suppose $p$ is a boundary point of $B$ so define $f(p)= lim_{x\rightarrow p}g(x)$ where the limit is taken from all possible direction? am I correct?

Comment: I am not getting it properly Dear Sir

Comment: Follow Rahul's further hint.